# POWER BI-If match multiple columns from one table to another table

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a two tables are Table1 and Table2, Table 1 is my data and Table 2 is Report. Table 1 and Table 2 contain the following headers "Fruit List", "Area Code" and Sales code". In Table 2 columns A to C are matched from Table 1 columns A to c then the status is "YES" if not matched then the status is "NO".

I can't use merge the query options here because it's creating lot of duplication line items. (I have unique data base around 322000 line items, when I try use the merge option it will create a lot duplicated line items) So I am looking for DAX measure or M language solutions options.

**Example for line item 2;** (In Table 2 Data) The item is 123 the fruit list is "Avocado" with area code is "3100" it's matched to my master data Table 1 therefore the status is "YES".

**Example for line item 5;** (In Table 2 Data) The item is 126 the fruit list is "Avocado" with area code is "West" it's not matched to my master data Table 1 therefore the status is "NO".

The "Avocado" "area code" belongs to only the following sales code (EU01,US,UK).

**Example for line item 19;** The item is 56 the fruit list is "watermelon" doesn't have a area code. Please refer the above mentioned snapshot.

Match criteria: The matching selection criteria is "Fruit list", "area code" and "sales code" in both tables.

Herewith attached the file for your reference.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2a4fqng58c4z59/IF%20MATCH%20ONE%20SHEET%20TO%20ANOTHER%20SHEET.pbix?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oebfzind62o68fg/IF%20MATCH.xlsx?dl=0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQPbj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create relationship betweent this tabel.
First create column
in TABLE1:

> JoinCol = COMBINEVALUES(" ",'TABLE1'[AREA CODE],'TABLE1'[SALES CODE],'TABLE1'[FRUIT LIST])

in TABLE2:

> JoinCol = JoinCol = COMBINEVALUES(" ",'TABLE2'[AREA CODE],'TABLE2'[SALES CODE],'TABLE2'[FRUIT LIST])

[image]

Then you Can make easily any calculation for example in Table2:

```
Output = if(LOOKUPVALUE(TABLE1[JoinCol],TABLE1[JoinCol],TABLE2[JoinCol]) = BLANK(),"NO","YES")
```

[image]

You can try also use UNION with INTERSECT and EXCEPT:

```
Table = UNION(
ADDCOLUMNS(INTERSECT(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(TABLE1[FRUIT LIST],TABLE1[AREA CODE],TABLE1[SALES CODE]), SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(TABLE2[FRUIT LIST],TABLE2[AREA CODE],TABLE2[SALES CODE])), "IF?","YES"),

ADDCOLUMNS(EXCEPT(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(TABLE2[FRUIT LIST],TABLE2[AREA CODE],TABLE2[SALES CODE]),SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(TABLE1[FRUIT LIST],TABLE1[AREA CODE],TABLE1[SALES CODE])),"IF?","NO"))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your solutions and guideline. Your first solution working well. I am struggling to apply your second solution. Could you please advise How and where can I apply your UNION with INTERSECT and EXCEPT? (In custom column or DAX measure?

Comment: when I try apply the measure in new column I am receiving the following error message "The expression refer to multiple columns. Multiple columns can not be convert to a scaler value." Could you please attach the final output file.

Comment: Sorry. I got it. It was new table. Sorry I am new to Power Bi that's the reason. Your 2nd solution picking wrong output for item 56 watermelon.  Herewith attached the file and snapshot for your reference.  Could you please advise. https://www.dropbox.com/s/udkg65d40gndbw4/IF%20MATCH%20NEW%20TBLE.pbix?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/tq4iruisrvqnmln/IF%20MATCH-SOF1.PNG?dl=0.

Comment: In Your TABLE1  AREACODE for watermelon is 0 length, but in TABLE2 when I check the length its give NULL (simply add NewColumn len(TABLE1[AreaCode]) ), that's why the output is wrong. Check your source data.

Comment: Hi. thank you for your advise. Now it's working fine. The last two question please, if I have blanks rows in table 2 then  SUMMARIZECOLUMNS measure populated the same thing in new table or need to be add new function? I will bring it Table 2 item in the same measure is that right?  could you please advise. dropbox.com/s/tq4iruisrvqnmln/IF%20MATCH-SOF1.PNG?dl=0

Comment: https://dax.guide/summarizecolumns/

 Only rows for which at least one of the supplied expressions return a non-blank value are included in the table returned. If all expressions evaluate to BLANK for a row, that row is not included in the table returned.

If we want bring back rows with blanks measures, we should use on this calculation IGNORE() function; Without calculation, like in our example you get everything.

When you add ITEM to TABLE1 in summarizecolumns, you get cartesian result without relationship between this two table, but output should be ok.

Comment: thank you so much for your help and clarify my issue. Thanks a lot .